# Can NetLogo incorporate an agent with 2 blind spots using in-cone or in-radius?

Tags: netlogo

Many animals have eyes located on the side of their heads rather than the front. This means they have 2 cones of vision with blind spots directly in front and behind.

Is there a way to program this in NetLogo?

Comment: You can have temporarily turn the turtle to the direction of vision you want, use `in-cone`, then restore the turtle's original heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are different solutions to achieve this.
One solution would be to first identify all patches in the front blind spot.
Then in a second step, identify all patches in a larger cone consisting of the front blind-spot patches and the side-vision patches but keep only those
patches which are not a member of the front blind-spot patchset.

```
  ask turtles
  [  
    ;; define angles
    let full-angle 260
    let blind-front-angle 70
    let vision-distance 40

    let blind-front patches in-cone vision-distance blind-front-angle  
    let vision patches in-cone vision-distance full-angle with [not member? self blind-front]

    ask vision [set pcolor red]
  ]
```

In the code example, the `full-angle parameter` is used to indirectly define the size of the blind-spot in the back, which is 360 - full-angle.
The `blind-front-angle`parameter defines the size of the blind-spot in front directly.